# Redux-form: Validate on change for file input

Tags: javascript, redux-form

I have a redux-form, with the following field in it:

```
<Field name="image" label="Image" accept="image/*" fileChangeHandler={ this._fileChangeHandler.bind(this) } component={ renderFileInputField } />

  _fileChangeHandler = e => {
    let fileList = e.target.files;
    let { touched, error } = this.props;
    if (fileList instanceof FileList && fileList.length > 0 && touched && !error) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = ({ target }) => {
        if (target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
          let imagePreview = <img src={ target.result } />;
          this.setState({
            imagePreview: imagePreview
          });
        }
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0]);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        imagePreview: <noscript/>
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is the renderer function:

```
export const renderFileInputField = function({ input, id, accept, label, fileChangeHandler, meta: { touched, error } }) {
  return renderField(<input {...input} id={id} type="file" onChange={ fileChangeHandler } accept={accept} value={null}/>
  , id, label, touched, error);
}
const renderField = function(input, id, label, touched, error) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <div>
        { input }
        { touched && error && <span>{error}</span> }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wonder:

1. How can I access `touched` and `error` in `_fileChangeHandler` function?
2. As redux validation happens on `onBlur`, how can I make it work on `onChange`?

Comment: tip: use [object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images) instead of base64

Comment: does it help with accessing `touched` and `error`? or validation `onChange`?